# Finite transcendence degree implies that every endomorphism is an automorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

In our last lecture, our algebra professor stated this result as a commentary, but i'm having some difficulties to prove it, mainly because i am still learning this subject:

- Let $E/K$ be an extension, with $E$ an algebraically closed field with finite transcendence degree over $K$. Then, every $K$-endomorphism of $E$ is an automorphism.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $f:E\to E$ is a $K$-endomorphism.  Then we have a tower of field extensions $K\subseteq f(E)\subseteq E$ and $$\operatorname{trdeg}(E/K)=\operatorname{trdeg}(E/f(E))+\operatorname{trdeg}(f(E)/K).$$  But $\operatorname{trdeg}(f(E)/K)=\operatorname{trdeg}(E/K)$ since $f:E\to f(E)$ is a $K$-isomorphism, and since this common value is finite, the equation above implies $\operatorname{trdeg}(E/f(E))=0$.  That is, $E$ is algebraic over $f(E)$.  But $f(E)$ is algebraically closed, so this implies $E=f(E)$.  That is, $f$ is surjective and hence an automorphism.